# React Native Navigation: screen flickers when function interacts with SecureStorage

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, flicker

The left gif shows the flickering of the screen when the `Switch` is pressed and the right image shows the screen at the moment when the flickering happens. That means that my `Stack.Screen` from `@react-navigation/native-stack`, that displays the `Settings` page gets removed for a small moment when the Switch is pressed, which results in the flicker effect.

[image]
[image]

The function that gets called when the Switch is pressed is my `toggleLocalAuth` function. This is an asynchronous function, so my guess would be that the screen flickers when the `toggleLocalAuth` is running.

```js
const toggleLocalAuth = async () => {
  await SecureStorage.save('local-auth', JSON.stringify(!usesLocalAuth))
  setUsesLocalAuth((usesLocalAuth) => !usesLocalAuth)
}
```

This is my `Security` component which contains the `Switch` and the "Security" subheader.

```js
const Security: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  const { usesLocalAuth, toggleLocalAuth } = useAuth()

  return (
    <Box>
      <Text variant="subheader" paddingHorizontal="m" paddingBottom="xs">
        {i18n.t('settings.security')}
      </Text>
      <Paper>
        <Box
          flexDirection="row"
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="space-between"
        >
          <Box flexDirection="row">
            <Ionicons
              name="finger-print"
              size={24}
              color={theme.colors.icon}
              style={{ paddingRight: theme.spacing.m }}
            />
            <Text variant="subtitle">
              {Platform.OS === 'ios' || Platform.OS === 'macos'
                ? i18n.t('settings.touchId')
                : i18n.t('settings.fingerprint')}
            </Text>
          </Box>
          <Switch value={usesLocalAuth} onValueChange={toggleLocalAuth} />
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

This is my whole screen that is shown in the image, which is a component of a `StackNavigator` Screen from `@react-navigation/native-stack`.

```js
const Settings = ({
  navigation,
}: {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<SessionParamList, 'Settings'>
}) => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ paddingVertical: theme.spacing.m }}>
      <Profile
        onPersonalPress={() => navigation.push('PersonalData')}
        onResidencePress={() => navigation.push('Residence')}
        onContactPress={() => navigation.push('ContactInformation')}
      />
      <Preferences />
      <Security />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

export default Settings
```

This is the `StackNavigator` Screen which holds the `Settings` page.

```js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<SessionParamList>()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

function SettingsStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          ...stackOptions,
          headerTitle: i18n.t('settings.settings'),
        }}
        name="Settings"
        component={Settings}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

My guess is that the `Settings` `Stack.Screen` gets removed for a small moment when the async `toggleLocalAuth` function is called. The background and `Tabbar` do not flicker because they are defined as `screenOptions` on my `Tab.Navigator` which sits above the `Settings` page in the component tree.

## Edit:

I use `useContext` and `createContext` to gloablly manage the authentication state.

```js
export type ContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean
  usesLocalAuth: boolean
  jwt: string
  logout: () => void
  login: (jwt: string) => void
  toggleLocalAuth: () => void
}

const AuthContext = createContext<ContextType>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  jwt: '',
  usesLocalAuth: false,
  logout: () => console.warn('Not Auth provider above component'),
  login: () => console.warn('Not Auth provider above component'),
  toggleLocalAuth: () => console.warn('Not Auth provider above component'),
})

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)
```

These are the relevant excerpts of my `App.tsx` file:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [usesLocalAuth, setUsesLocalAuth] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [jwt, setJwt] = useState('')

  function logout() {
    setIsAuthenticated(false)
    setDid(null)
  }
  function login(jwt: string) {
    setIsAuthenticated(true)
    setJwt(jwt)
  }

  const authProvider = useMemo(
    () => ({
      isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
      jwt: jwt,
      usesLocalAuth: usesLocalAuth,
      logout: logout,
      login: login,
      toggleLocalAuth: toggleLocalAuth,
    }),
    [isAuthenticated, usesLocalAuth, did, jwt, logout, login, toggleLocalAuth],
  ...
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authProvider}>
      ...
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
)
```

Comment: Is this state is managed at global level (i.e fingerprint slider button state) ?

Comment: Yea it's manage the state in the `App.tsx` file and use `createContext`. I will add the state management to my question.

Comment: Any logs in metro server that might help ?

Comment: No, nothing. But issues regarding flickering + React Navigation are pretty common on GIthub. But in these issues the flickering mostly appears while navigating. In my case the flickering only happens when my asnyc function is called and `usesLocalAuth` state is changed.